# Possible to Search 'Standard' Community Pages?

Tags: apex, community, search

### Background

I've created 'Standard' pages in my 'Customer Service' community via the Experience Builder. These pages include '[Rich Content Editor](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_rich_text_component.htm&type=5)' Lightning components, which contains text. We would like this text to be searchable.

### Issue

It seems like no matter what we do, we can't get 'Standard' community pages to appear in the search results.

### Things We Have Tried

We have tried using both the **Global Search for Peer-to-Peer Communities** and **Global Search Box** search components. Either way, [Global Search Results](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_search_global.htm&type=5) seems to only allow 'objects' to appear in the results.

It looks like this is because community pages are only stored as metadata in Salesforce - and this can't be searched. Furthermore, we haven't been able to access these community pages via Workbench or the Metadata API.

We have also created a case with Salesforce, but no joy yet.

### Question

1. Is it possible to search 'standard' community pages using the native community search functionality?
2. If not, is this possible via custom development?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not possible to search the keyword that you put in the community builder.
2. Only alternative custom solution i can think of is using a custom object and putting your data into a rich text field. Rich text fields are searchable in salesforce.

Note that you will have to build a [custom component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedRichText/example) to display it. You can use the `lightning:formattedRichText` for this to support rich text format.

Comment: Thanks Mohith. If I follow your response to the second question, you're not suggesting we use community 'Record' pages. Rather, we still use the 'Standard' community pages, build a custom component in order to pull rich text from a custom object record in Salesforce, and insert the custom component in the page. We then make this custom object appear in the search results. In this case, when a user performs a search and clicks on the custom object record, they will be taken to the 'Record' page for the custom object, not the 'Standard' community page that we created, which doesn't help us.

Comment: A) Did I understand your solution correctly? If so, do you have any suggestions as to how we can make the 'Standard' community page appear in the search results? B) Is it possible to automatically create custom object records based on 'Standard' community pages?

Comment: Sorry trying to be helpful. What i am recommending is as an community admin they will need to go to custom object to add record and your component displays that record and when  actual user does a search, it will take you to object standard page that has standard layout with this custom component